# Github pages w/ Jekyll 404 on specific page

Tags: ruby, git, jekyll, github-pages

I am currently having an issue with Github Pages

I guess it doesn't hurt to use the actual [live example](https://scotta38.github.io/)

The corresponding repo is https://github.com/ScottA38/ScottA38.github.io

I made some styling changes (maybe some JS changes I don't remember) ages ago when I was actively working on the content, and somehow ever since the 'projects' page has been 404 when I try and click through to it from the menu.

I am using [Jekyll theme Jam](https://github.com/desiredpersona/jekyll-theme-jam) which is some obscure obsolete theme, but I don't see it being a problem really

The strangest part is that if I load the site locally with `bundle exec jekyll serve` then this page appears perfectly at `localhost:4000/projects`, just not on the live site

If I put `https://scotta38.github.io/projects.html` (live site) it also appears perfectly, just not at `https://scotta38.github.io/projects` like I want

I have seen some suggestions about GH servers caching an old version or something like this but I don't really understand and I need some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"About" page works and [you have a permalink there](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScottA38/ScottA38.github.io/master/about.md), but [nothing for projects](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScottA38/ScottA38.github.io/master/projects.md).
Probably adding

```
permalink: /projects/
```

will fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice - where do I add this?

Comment: In the front matter of the `projects.md`